# Analog reading in raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi

I am trying to read an analog input using a raspberry pi zero W, but all of the GPIO are digital. Can you guys maybe suggest on how to get around this or maybe point me to forums or guide regarding the matter? I am also a beginner in using raspberry pi. all response would be appreciated

Comment: what sort of precision, accuracy, and read rate do you need? there may be other ways, eg: the IBM PC analogue joystick doesn't have a DAC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No analog input on the raspberry pi sorry.
You either can use digital input and ADConverter or using I2C or SPI Bus with a sensor using one of these protocols.

[ADS1115](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1085) is an I2C 16 bit four channel ADC.

Comment: If the sample rate is low, Onewire is also an option, e.g. DS2450 or DS2438. The latter also has a calibrated temperature sensor built in as it is meant for battery management.

Comment: The system will read a data when a button is pressed. thank you for the response, I will look into it